# How to get the output of `doc` function in clojure?

Tags: clojure

I tried to save the output of the `doc` function, eg:

```
user> (def doc-str-split (doc str/split))
-------------------------
clojure.string/split
([s re] [s re limit])
  Splits string on a regular expression.  Optional argument limit is
  the maximum number of splits. Not lazy. Returns vector of the splits.
#'user/doc-str-split

user> doc-str-split
nil
user>
```

However, I got `nil` for the `doc-str-split`. I tried to get the `type` of the `doc` output:

```
user> (type (doc str/split))
-------------------------
clojure.string/split
([s re] [s re limit])
  Splits string on a regular expression.  Optional argument limit is
  the maximum number of splits. Not lazy. Returns vector of the splits.
nil
```

Still get a `nil`. How to save the output of the `doc` function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`with-out-str`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/with-out-str) to capture the output, like so:

```
user> (def doc-str-split (with-out-str (doc str/split)))
#'user/doc-str-split

user> (println doc-str-split)
-------------------------
clojure.string/split
([s re] [s re limit])
  Splits string on a regular expression.  Optional argument limit is
  the maximum number of splits. Not lazy. Returns vector of the splits.

nil

user> (type (with-out-str (doc str/split)))
java.lang.String
```

Comment: Ah, didn't know about this function. Thanks!

Comment: `Clojure` is full of surprising yet useful functions. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can get just the doc string like so:

```
user.core=> (def doc (prn (:doc (meta #'clojure.string/split))))
"Splits string on a regular expression.  Optional argument limit is  
 the maximum number of splits. Not lazy. Returns vector of the splits."
```